# Verify a value is bigger/smaller than a Buffer

Tags: tosca

I want to write an input in an value box and at the same time I want to verify that this value is bigger than another value saved in a Buffer.

Example:

- 2 Buffers are saved:

  1. Buffer1 = 300
  2. Buffer2 = 500
- I want Buffer1 as Input in this value Box and at the same time I want to verify that:
  Buffer1 > Buffer2

Do you have an idea how we could do that?

Answer (score 1):

Verifying works like this

[image]

```
 {B[buffer1]}<{B[buffer2]}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to enter Buffer 1 as Input and Verify it at the same time. Is that possible? This is not a table but a normal Inputbox.

Comment: please clarify your question. What is "normal input box"?

Comment: For example: Net value : Input Box in SAP (and you just scanned this input Box where you put the value in and verify it with comparison to another value)

Comment: I dont understand the use case of it. You are who is defining what is entered into input box. Why do you need to verify it?

Comment: Well yes, but before I enter the value I want to make sure, that the price for example is und a special limit. And I thought it would be best, if I could do that in the same Input box. Or do you think it would be better to use the evaluation Tool and just entering the value if the condition is fulfilled?

Comment: You KNOW what value you enter. If you enter 300 you already know that 300 is less than 500. What's the point of verifying it?

Comment: That is not the question. The question is whether this is possible and if it is, how do you do it.